# Creating image on a pixel-by-pixel basis from data-array with Swift

Tags: swift, image, bitmap

I'm trying to create an image (8-bit greyscale bitmap ?) from a dataset that I have acquired (it features x-y-coordinates and the actual pixel-data-information 0-255).

Now I would like to do that by using Apple's Cocoa/Foundation/etc. frameworks in Swift, but I just can't seem to grasp the idea of how it is even possible.

I really don't need to do any additional image-manipulation other than creating this simple greyscale-image.

So basic workflow would look like this:

1. initialize image by size as 8-bit greyscale
2. fill each pixel with the appropriate information from the array
3. save the image into a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet of code that I slapped together which does actually save a bmp-file with my data. So it does work. Absolutely not good code, I assume. But I was just trying to get a working example, which I would refine later.

```
var myImageDataArray : [UInt8] = [167, 241, 217, 42, 130, 200, 216, 254, 67, 77, 152, 85, 140, 226, 179, 71]
let dataProv = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, myImageDataArray, myImageDataArray.count, nil)
let myCG = CGImageCreate(4, 4, 8, 8, 4, CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGrayGamma2_2), CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrderDefault, dataProv, nil, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
let testTIFF = NSBitmapImageRep(CGImage: myCG!)
let mynewData = testTIFF.representationUsingType(NSBitmapImageFileType.NSTIFFFileType, properties: [NSImageCompressionMethod: 1])
mynewData?.writeToFile("testTIFF.tiff", atomically: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [UInt8] representation of the image your code will look like this:

```
let imgBytes = // image array [UInt8]
let imgData = NSData(bytes: imgBytes, length: imgBytes.count)
UIImage(data: imgData)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I started to think a little differently about this problem and I managed to get kind of what I wanted now. See below.